# Transfering mirrored disks to different computer

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, raid, disk-space, disk-management

I had two 3TB HDDs on my old computer. These were setup to be mirrored using Window's Disk Management util.

I am now trying to use those two HDDs on my new computer. I plugged them in using the standard SATA connectors, then I turned on my computer and went into Disk Management. Inside Disk Management I tried to do "Import Foreign Disks" but it didn't seem to work and now both disks are showing up as "Failed" (See image below).

[image: disk management screenshot]

The disks do show up as a dynamic mirror so it looks like it recognises them being a mirrored setup but I can't access the contents of the disks.

I ran `mountvol` to get a GUID for the disks so that I could run `chkdsk` and these are the outputs:

Disk 0:
[image: chkdsk on disk 0]

Disk 1:

[image: chkdsk on disk 1]

What are my options from here? I would like if possible to recover some of the data from these disks.

I do not have access to the old computer.

Comment: Did you follow the steps in [Move disks to another computer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/disk-management/move-disks-to-another-computer)?

Comment: Do you see your files on one or the two disks (separately)?

Comment: @AndrewMorton No, the previous computer was damaged and the disks had to be unplugged without "uninstalling" them.

Comment: @harrymc No I can't see either of the disks in File Explorer

Comment: What kind of mirroring have you used?

Comment: @harrymc Just the Windows mirroring you get in Disk Management. Right click an unallocated drive and select "New Mirrored Volume". I'm guessing it's a software RAID 1.

Comment: The simplest solution would be to backup the data, format and recreate the mirror, if you have the space for it.

Comment: @harrymc I am not sure I understand. How do I backup the data? I can't access the drives' contents. I don't really care about the mirroring at this point, I'd just like to see the contents of one of the drives and grab some files from it.

Comment: Questions: (1) When in Disk Management you right-click the mirror, do you have the option of "Break Mirror"? (2) Is the contained data irreplaceable if the contents are lost?

Comment: @harrymc (1) No break mirror option. I can only do 'delete volume' or 'reactivate disk' which does nothing. (2) That is the only copy of that data yes but it's not anything massively important in there.

Comment: Try [ReclaiMe Free RAID Recovery software](http://www.freeraidrecovery.com/raid-recovery-tutorial.aspx), the only free RAID recovery product that I know. If it doesn't help, the next question will be if you're willing to invest in a commercial product.

Comment: @harrymc ReclaiMe does recognise both disks as being a near identical copy, but ReclaiMe only does RAID 0 or 5 and not RAID 1 so it's not actually able to do anything. Did you have any commercial product in mind? It's hard to tell what's legit and what's not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each of the disks participating in the mirror should be an
exact copy and readable by itself. However, since you tried
to import the two disks as one RAID, Windows has confused the issue.

If the data is important, you could attempt to retrieve it by
connecting one of the disks to another computer, or to this
computer inside an enclosure, so Windows will not recognize it
as part of this broken RAID.

If nothing works and the data is not important, you could delete
the volume and format the two disks, then create the new RAID.

Otherwise, you will need a recovery program :

- [ReclaiMe Free RAID Recovery software](http://www.freeraidrecovery.com/raid-recovery-tutorial.aspx)
  is free, but doesn't do RAID1
- Another freebie is
  [iCare Data Recovery Free](https://www.icare-recovery.com/)
  (*Note: This one was slow, but recovered all the poster's data*)
- [Yodot RAID Data Recovery](https://www.yodot.com/hard-drive-recovery/raid-recovery.html)
  seems to be free now
- [MiniTool](https://www.minitool.com/data-recovery/raid-recovery-software.html)
  ($69)
- [Wondershare](https://recoverit.wondershare.com/free-data-recovery/free-raid-recovery.html)
- [Recover My Files](https://getdata.com/recovermyfiles/)
  ($69.95)
- [EaseUS Data Recovery Wizard Professional](https://www.easeus.com/datarecoverywizardpro/)
  ($69.95/month with trial).
- [GetDataBack Pro](https://www.runtime.org/data-recovery-software.htm)
  ($79)

References :

- [Top 6 RAID Recovery Software](https://www.stellarinfo.com/article/best-raid-recovery-software.php)
- [Top 5 RAID Data Recovery Software](https://recoverit.wondershare.com/harddrive-recovery/top-5-raid-hard-drive-data-recovery.html?keywords=Videospiel&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI8NCz1Jy67QIVy56zCh2MRQliEAAYAyAAEgLopPD_BwE)

Comment: Thanks, I checked the disks with GetDataBack Pro which has a free test version and I can see all of the data is intact. Now I will figure out which way works best for me to actually recover the files.

Comment: Just to update anyone that makes it to here, I ended up using iCare Data Recovery Free. It is a bit slow but worked wonders and recovered all the files I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Run both disks in your old computer and transfer your files to the new computer using a network connection.

Comment: Not sure why my first comment disappeared. I don't have access to the old computer anymore.

Comment: @valegians - It was deleted because it was no longer necessary since it now appears in your question.